# How to read bucketed hive table in Spark 2.x

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

Hello how can we to read this bucketed hive table in Spark 2.x. Even in spark github example they have explained write to bucketed table. Read operation is  not explained.

I have also tried to read bucketed column as example explained in https://blog.deepsense.ai/optimize-spark-with-distribute-by-and-cluster-by/
.But still I am not able to read bucketed table in spark. Please suggest if you have any idea reading this.

Comment: same with you. i really really hope they fix this problem.